# How to remove empty lines of a selected region of code in Emacs?

Tags: replace, whitespace, query-replace, newlines

Is there a way to remove blank lines from a region of code I select?

I am asking because I copy/pasted code and it seems to have several blank lines I want to get rid off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select what you want to change, or `C-x h` to select the whole buffer.
2. Then: `M-x flush-lines RET` followed by `^$ RET` or `^[[:space:]]*$ RET`

`^[[:space:]]*$` contain the meta-characters:

- `^` for beginning of string,
- `$` for end of string,
- `[[:space:]]*` zero or more spaces.

Ergo, if the first two meta-characters are next to each other or if there is one or more spaces between them, it must be a blank line. [Source](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/removing-blank-lines-buffer)

You may eventually be interested by [shrink-whitespace](https://github.com/jcpetkovich/shrink-whitespace.el)